# Finding the discriminant

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Stewart and Tall's book on algebraic number theory, we come across the example where we find the integral basis of $Q (\sqrt2 , i)$. We guess the basis to be {$1,i,\sqrt 2, i\sqrt 2$}. The discriminant is said to be -64. When I try to compute the basis, I get the matrix to be $$\begin{matrix}
1 & i & \sqrt 2 & i\sqrt 2\\
1 & -i & \sqrt 2 & -i\sqrt 2\\
1 & i & -\sqrt 2 & -i\sqrt 2\\
1 & -i & -\sqrt 2 & i\sqrt 2\\
\end{matrix}$$.
The determinant of the matrix is 32 and square of 32 is not -64. I must have made some error in forming the matrix but cannot really find it out.

Comment: I think your calculation is right.  Why do you say the discriminant is $-64$?

Comment: I know that the calculation is correct. In the book the discriminant is given to be -64 without any supporting calculation. I am verifying that. I guess I have made a mistake in forming the matrix which too is not there in the book.

Comment: Maybe you are right and the book is wrong

Comment: The discriminant can't be negative.  Discriminants of different bases differ by square factors, so they all share the same sign, and the basis of powers of $i + \sqrt{2}$ has positive discriminant $2^{14}3^2$. More conceptually, the sign of the discriminant of a number field is $(-1)^{r_2}$, where $r_2$ is the number of pairs of complex conjugate embeddings. The field $\mathbf Q(i,\sqrt{2})$ has $r_2 = 2$, so $(-1)^{r_2} = 1$.

Comment: The correct value of the discriminant of this field is $256$, not $-64$. Your chosen basis has discriminant $32^2 = 1024 = 4 \cdot 256$, so your chosen basis is not going to span all the algebraic integers of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2},i)$ over $\mathbf Z$.  An example of an algebraic integer you missed is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{2}$, which is actually $e^{2\pi i/8}$.  Your field is the $8$th cyclotomic field.

Comment: There is a series of exercises in Marcus' *Number Fields* (around page 50) that works out the ring of integers of every biquadratic field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$.

Comment: @KCd Yes, the discriminant of this basis turns out to be 1024. Just that the book is saying that it is -64.